# С# DataGridView how to display cell value by a known value in a string

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my `DataGridView` I have 3 columns: Bank, DataBuy, and DataSell.

I found `Max` and `Min` values using this code:

```
double[] columnDataBuy = (
     from DataGridViewRow row 
     in DataGridView1.Rows 
     where row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty 
     select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue))
    .ToArray();
// Assigning value to TextBox
textBoxBuy.Text=columnDataBuy.Max().ToString();


double[] columnDataSell = (
    from DataGridViewRow row 
    in DataGridView1.Rows 
    where row.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty 
    select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].FormattedValue))
    .ToArray();
textBoxSell.Text=columnDataSell.Min().ToString();
```

This assigns the min or max value to the `TextBox`, but what I want instead is the value in the **Bank** column to go there. How can I obtain the value for **Bank** from my `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sample, you have a `DataGridView` with columns [Bank|DataBuy|DataSell] and you are looking for a way to assign a string value for **Bank** to `textBoxBuy` and `textBoxSell` after obtaining `Max` from **DataBuy** and `Min` from **DataSell**. One approach that would make this much simpler would be using [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for your `DataGridView1`.

If you make a class to represent the properties that you name in your post:

```
class Record
{
    public string Bank { get; set; }
    public double DataBuy { get; set; }
    public double DataSell { get; set; }
}
```

And then make a `BindingList` of records:

```
BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
```

Then this will generate the DataGridView columns using the public properties of your Record class. (This occurs by adding the first `Record`.) You **attach** the binding source in this way:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if(!DesignMode)
    {
        DataGridView1.DataSource = this.DataSource;
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        DataSource.Add(new Record { Bank = "Bank-1", DataBuy = 2.00, DataSell=1.0});
        DataSource.Add(new Record { Bank = "Bank-2", DataBuy = 1.00, DataSell=0.0});

        TryItThisWay();
    }
}
BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
```

And this makes it very easy to obtain the strings you want for your TextBoxes by `using System.Linq`:

```
void TryItThisWay()
{
    // Using Linq to sort the DataBuy and choose the record with the highest
    Record recordMax = DataSource.OrderByDescending(record=>record.DataBuy).First();
    // Now you can obtain the Bank property from the Record.
    textBoxBuy.Text = recordMax.Bank;

    // Using Linq to sort the DataSell and choose the record with the lowest
    Record recordMin = DataSource.OrderBy(record=>record.DataSell).First();
    textBoxSell.Text = recordMin.Bank;
}
```

In this way, you can achieve the outcome in your post.

[image]